# Not able to validate string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
echo "enter variable" 
    read var
    if[[ ${var} = ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,25}$ ]];then
        echo "valid" 
    else
        echo "invalid" 
    fi
```

I'm trying to validate(starting with a character followed by alphanumeric, no special character). 26 characters allowed. 
For every input, it gives `valid`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: In a `[[ ]]` test, the `=` operator does string or wildcard pattern matching; for regular expression matching, use `=~`. Also, you need a space between `if` and `[[`.

Comment: I recommend that you put your regex pattern in a variable and use the variable in the match test. For this pattern it's not essential, but for others it is; so it's a good habit. `pattern='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,25}$'; if [[ $var =~ $pattern ]]; then`. The reason is that patterns with some characters such as spaces need to be quoted, but if you quote either the pattern or a variable containing the pattern inside the match test then it becomes a string equality test instead. (Also you're missing the `then`)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson pattern in a variable worked.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (please note the tilde):

```
echo "enter variable" 
read var 
if [[ ${var} =~ ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,25}$ ]] ; then
  echo "valid" 
else 
  echo "invalid" 
fi
```